# Алгоритмическая сложность операций с NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, c++

Как ответить на следующих вопрос? Он будет на собеседовании на работу

Опишите алгоритмическую сложность следующих операций для `NSMutableArray` в среднем и в худшем случаях:

1. вставка нового элемента в начало структуры;
2. вставка нового элемента в конец структуры;
3. поиск существующего элемента по значению;
4. поиск существующего элемента по индексу;
5. удаление существующего элемента.

Какую структуру данных вы бы использовали для реализации `NSMutableArray` с учётом ваших требований к алгоритмической сложности?

Comment: Неплохая статья по теме: [Exposing NSMutableArray](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/)

Comment: Да, интересно. Насколько я понял, идея в цикличности массива и наличии свободного места в середине. 

Т.е. в начале все элементы, конечно, размещаются с начала выделенной области (в конце есть пустое место). А вот при вставке элемента в начало, он добавляется в конец пустого места и указатель на первый элемент начинает указывать на него.

При изменении размера выделенной области (даже если аллокатор добавит смежные байты) часть элементов массива придется копировать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В оффициальной документации подобного нет (в явном виде), что и следовало ожидать.

Но почитав детально, стает понятно, что ничего нового изобрести в Эппл не могли, и скорее всего там следующее.

> а) вставка нового элемента в начало структуры;

в этом случае нужно выделить место под новый элемент, скопировать все элементы, сдвинув индексы на 1 и вставить новый элемент. Перемещение элементов имеет сложность O(n). Выделение памяти обычно константное, если размеры небольшие. При больших размерах (десятках и сотнях мегабайт) сложность нужно рассматривать отдельно. Поэтому, на небольших объемах массива вставка нового элемента в начало - это O(n). На большом размере массива нужно смотреть в менеджер памяти.

> б) вставка нового элемента в конец структуры;

в академическом смысле эта задача сводиться к выделению нового объема памяти переносу всех элементов и вписыванию в конец нового элемента. То есть, по факту, ничем не отличается от предыдущей. Но тут научились делать одну оптимизацию. Памяти выделяют немного больше, чем нужно и в результате выделения памяти (и копирование всего массива) происходит не часто. Если копирование не происходит, то сложность добавления в конец - O(1). Документация косвенно подтверждает, что память выделяется с запасом.

> в) поиск существующего элемента по значению;

здесь документация однозначно говорит, что сложность O(n) - пробегают по всему списку элементов, пока не найдут нужный.

> г) поиск существующего элемента по индексу;

здесь обычно, если ничего не постарались сделать, то сложность константная, O(1), потому что просто нужно умножить индекс на размер элемента и приплюсовать начало массива.

> д) удаление существующего элемента.

здесь все то же самое, что и при добавлении элементов. Единственно, что память никто не уменьшает.

Comment: Да, malloc/realloc для больших объемов использует mmap, поэтому увеличение выделенной области может быть очень быстрым (модифицируется только таблица страниц виртуальной памяти процесса, (думаю, время O(log M), где М количество областей, выделенных через mmap))

Из [mallopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html)


    Nowadays, glibc uses a dynamic mmap threshold by default.  The initial value of the threshold is 128*1024

Comment: А разве где-то в документации сказано что NSArray/NSMutableArray реализованы через последовательно расположеные в памяти массивы? Скорее всего так и есть, но реальных указаний в документации что-то с ходу не нашел, а если у нас, скажем, список (а у кого-то типа qt вроде уже подобный финт был - класс с названием вектор по факту был реализован через список) то как минимум все перемещения массива в памяти при вставке-удалении пропадают

ПС попытался поправить пост чтобы ссылки вели куда надо, почему-то не получается

Comment: Не думаю, что править чужие ответы -- это хорошая идея.

Comment: сам посмотрел на ссылки - как то странно они парсятся. Пока привью ответа - все нормально, но после сохранения...

> А разве где-то в документации сказано что NSArray/NSMutableArray реализованы через последовательно расположеные в памяти массивы?

По другому было бы делать глупо. Я конечно понимаю, что у них и шрифты вырвиглазные, и интерфейс жутко не интуитивный, кнопки назад/отмена по полчаса ищешь. (иногда коллегам по работе помогаешь с сим девайсом управиться - потом ходишь руки мыть и чаем отпаиваться), но врядли бы они делали по другому (хотя это Эппл. Они могут).

Comment: @avp , смысл править действительно плохая идея, а вот в том чтобы поправить слетевшие ссылки очень даже неплохая. Другой вопрос что сейчас похоже какие-то проблемы на хешкоде

@KoVadim , увы, я уже ничему не удивлюсь, эппл очень небрежно с сдк обращается - то енумы попереставляет, то введет что-то кровь из носу нужное в новой версии, но заставляющее падать старую, то даже объявит что давуно имевшееся свойство будет теперь отвечать за другое, а за старое отвечает новое. Да что там говорить, у них справочные примеры то не все из коробки работают

Comment: А вот тут как ответить: Какую структуру данных вы бы использовали для реализации NSMutableArray с учётом ваших требований к алгоритмической сложности?

Comment: @KoVadim, а с NSMutableDictionary все так же?

Comment: не так же конечно, там же пары ключ-значение, а не просто массив однотипных элементов. Вот только если вы этого не понимаете у меня очень большие сомнения стоит ли вам разъяснять чтобы вы обдурили будущего работодателя

Comment: @aknew, понимание на массив у меня появилось на основе вышеописанного текста, я очень был бы балгодарен за описание ситуации со словариками

Comment: @bibibi, наберите в гугле:

    nsmutabledictionary implementation

и читайте.

В http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/04/08/exposing-nsdictionary/ автор (тот же, что и в ссылке на реализацию NSMutableArray в одном из комментариев) исследует NSDictionary и находит хэш-таблицу с разрешением коллизий методом открытой адресации.

Про NSMutableDictionary он пишет:

    A mutable dictionary is, understandably, much more complex and the amount of disassembly I would have had to go through was terrifying.

Рискну предположить, что NSMutableDictionary реализуется хэш-таблицей с цепочками коллизий.

Comment: 
@KoVadim, можешь, пожалуйста, описать ситуацию с NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Если честно, то я не использую iPhone/MacOS. Немного писал под мак, но это были самые страшные часы в моей жизни.

Поэтому, я могу, конечно, пойти и поковырять стандартную доку от Эппл, но смысл?